# UITableView background with UIImage method imageNamed:resizableImageWithCapInsets:

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimage

i want know if it's possible set the background of a `UITableView` with a `UIImage` using this method:

```
imageNamed:resizableImageWithCapInsets:
```

i have a `UITableView` that have a dynamic size, so i really need this method for have a resizableImage. there is a way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Use an image view as the table's `backgroundView`.

Answer (score 0):

You can set UITableView.backgroundView as UIImageView with resizable image as mentioned below.

```
UIImage *bgImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"TableBG.png"];
int height = floorf(bgImage.size.height);
int width = floorf(bgImage.size.width);
UIEdgeInsets edgeInsert = UIEdgeInsetsMake((height-1)/2, (width-1)/2, (height-1)/2, (width-1)/2);
UIImage *resizableImage = [bgImage resizableImageWithCapInsets:edgeInsert resizingMode:UIImageResizingModeStretch];
self.tblScheduleList.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:resizableImage];
```

You can change edge insert and resizingMode.